# networkx draw nodes on a line in order with curved edges

Tags: python, networkx

I would like to draw a set of nodes on a line with spaces in between that correspond to the difference in a node property (here: the time when the node entered the system).
I would then like to draw curved edges between these nodes. Is this possible in networkx?

I have attached a sketch of the layout that I would like to achieve.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the position of your nodes by passing a dictionary of the positions (x,y) of your nodes to the `nx.draw` function (see doc [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw)). To add a curve to your arrows, you can use `connectionstyle=’arc3,rad=-0.7’` (with `rad` taking whatever value you want for the curve) in the `nx.draw` function (see doc [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html)).

See example below:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.DiGraph()
N_nodes=7

[G.add_node(i) for i in range(N_nodes)]

G.add_edge(0,1)
G.add_edge(2,4)
G.add_edge(2,5)

posx=[0,1,3,5,6,7,9]
posy=N_nodes*[0]
pos={i:[posx[i],posy[i]] for i in range(N_nodes)}

nx.draw(G,pos=pos,connectionstyle="arc3,rad=-0.7",edge_color='blue')
plt.ylim([-0.5,0.5])
```

[image]