# How to Create Scatter Plot with Multiple Connecting Lines in Python?

Tags: python, scatter-plot

How do I create a scatter plot with multiple connecting lines between plots based on similar values?
For example, I have a table like this:

[image: Example of Table]

And I need to create plot to something like this:

[image: Example of plot]

Thank you very much for the help, everyone!

**Update**
I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72858760/networkx-draw-nodes-on-a-line-in-order-with-curved-edges)

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()
N_nodes = 7

[G.add_node(i) for i in range(N_nodes)]

G.add_edge(0, 1)
G.add_edge(2, 4)
G.add_edge(2, 5)

posx = [0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9]
posy = N_nodes*[0]
pos = {i: [posx[i], posy[i]] for i in range(N_nodes)}

nx.draw(G, pos=pos, connectionstyle="arc3,rad=-0.7", edge_color='blue')
plt.ylim([-0.5, 0.5])
plt.show()
```

This technique produces a graph that matches my expectations, but one thing I'm still confused about is how to automatically detect a relationship between nodes based on the existence of the same value between these nodes. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: That's more of a graph than scatterplot.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ShlomiF I try one of example from plotly: https://plotly.com/python/lines-on-maps/ (US Flight Paths Map) but I can not figured out how to modify such longitude latitude and remove the maps